# Why does adding a semicolon sometimes break an if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Why is it that you aren't supposed to add semicolons after every set of curly braces? I thought this was a rule in JavaScript. In this code snippet, for instance, it turns out that it does not work because of the semicolon after the initial if statement, but then the semicolon after the else statement is fine.

```js
function a() {
  if (var >= length) {
    count =
      var / length;
  };
  else {
    count = 0
  };
```

Comment: because the else is part of the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the semicolon between the `if` and `else` effectively splits them into two separate blocks.

An `if` block can exist on its own, but not an `else` block, since the `else` depends on the condition in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Because the entire expression includes the `if` block. Semi-colons are introduced after the completion of an expression (and not necessary post `if` curly braces). When you add a semi-colon after the `if`, you are cutting the entire expression short.

You are, in a sense, saying:

```
if (foo === bar) {
    //do something
} /** You: Ok stop doing stuff**/;
/**
    Javascript: Ok! I'm done
**/
else { // Javascript: Wait, what is this crap
    //nothing's gonna happen
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon after the first `}` creates an empty statement. It's as if you wrote:

```
 alert('test');
 ;
```

This extra "empty" statement separates the `if` from the `else`, so the `else` block becomes meaningless.